# Power series expansion of $e^{\frac{c}{2}(z-1/z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

Show that

\begin{equation}
e^{\frac{c}{2}(z-1/z)}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_nz^n
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}
a_n:=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(n\theta-c\sin(\theta))d\theta
\end{equation}

Comment: This is an incredibly inconvenient - but known and understood - reference to the $J$-Bessel function. From that, my [answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758760/bessel-equations-addition-formula) also answers this question.

Comment: @mixedmath In the link that you sent me to, I believe you have a mistake/typo, you prove that $$e^{c/2(z-z^{-1})}=\sum J_n(x)z^n$$
which is contrary to your claim, however, thanks, I have been able to prove it

Comment: Since you know markup properly, can you please edit $z-1/z$ as $z-\frac{1}{z}$ or $\frac{z-1}{z}$ as appropriate? Thanks!

Comment: @MattAlegro, it can't mean anything but the former